# Symfony 2 How to create custom type to generate a custom directive

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I have a custom directive create on angular and I'd like to create a type on Symfony2 to generate my new custom directive. I know it might sound lazy but I'm really having a hard time understanding Symfony2's documentation on types and I can't figure out how to do this.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: do you speack about form type? if yes you can do someting like that : class directyveType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('comment', 'text', array(
                'required' => true,
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'style' => 'width:600px',
                    'class' => 'commentaire',
                    'placeholder' => ' Ajouter un commentaire',
                ),
            ))
        ;
    }

Comment: I have a custom element, lets say <newelement></newelement>. I want to create a custom type on symfony that generates <newelement> a not <input type="">. Is this possible?

Comment: i think is better to create it width angulars js

Comment: You have to override the twig function used to show it. It is possible but requires a lot of class overriding. Definitively not for the lazy.

Comment: its absolute unclear what you are asking to me. You should use javascript for that